# Fix the width of in-line style written without 'px or %' in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have to fix the width of in-line style written without 'px or %'.
**I can't modify the html and css in the page, but only the script.**
I want to read the width(only with javascript) to fix the missing unit measure.

The issue is only on IE 9. In chrome, FF, safari i can raed the width using the code below.

Using JQuery 1.8.2

```
/*script in head */
$(function() {
       var style = $("#test").attr("style"); 
       alert(style);
       //in IE it prints only color:red;border:1px solid red;
});

/* html in body */
<div id="test" style="width:20;color:red;border:1px solid red;">
    Content ...
</div>
```

An exaple on tis problem (IE problem) - >http://jsfiddle.net/2QJ96/1/

Comment: What you want just might not be possible.  No browser believes that a width is defined at all because it is invalid:  http://jsfiddle.net/2QJ96/3/.  If you're trying to fix this via JS by inserting the unit type, you're using entirely the wrong tool (the correct solution is to modify the HTML).

Answer (score 1):

You can just read the width by

```
$('#test').css('width');
```

Also, your HTML needs to be modified:

```
/* html in body */
<div id="test" style="width:20px; color:red; border:1px solid red;">
    Content ...
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean? If you can run JavaScript, then you can modify the HTML all you want - via JavaScript. It's incredibly hackish, but you can certainly do it.